# How to prevent an application stealing focus in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird, focus

When clicking a link in Thunderbird, Chrome automatically steals focus. I want to keep working in Thunderbird while clicking links open them in Chrome in the background - without stealing focus.

How can I do this?

Comment: Unfortunatelly gnome shell gives very little control on the focus behaviour. Try changing the dconf key /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/focus-new-windows using dconf-editor, but don'thold your breath.